# ¿Cómo consumir método de web api cuando el tamaño del payload es muy grande?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Desarrollo una Web API donde tengo un método  para insertar los datos de un payload en una tabla de la base de datos. Este método obtiene una lista de la clase Person la cual además de poseer varias propiedades también contiene dos campos (Foto y Qr ) que son de tipo String y contienen dichas imágenes en formato base 64, cuando los registros son pocos el método funciona correctamente, pero cuando se hace mayor la cantidad de registros el método no funciona.

Devuelve el siguiente error:

```
  StatusCode: 413, ReasonPhrase: 'Request Entity Too Large', Version: 1.1, Content:       System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
  {
    Connection: close
    Date: Sun, 15 Mar 2020 17:20:55 GMT
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Content-Length: 67
    Content-Type: text/html
}}
```

Metodo en el controlador de la api:

```
   [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("CreatePerson")]
        public HttpResponseMessage CreatePerson ([FromBody] List<Person> persons)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            if ( persons == null || persons.Count == 0)
            {
                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                response.Content = new StringContent(EngineData.modeloImcompleto, Encoding.Unicode);
                return response;
            }
            bool resultado = Metodo.CreatePerson(persons);
            if (!resultado)
            {
                response.Content = new StringContent(EngineData.falloCrearPersonas, Encoding.Unicode);
            }
            else
            {
                response.Content = new StringContent(EngineData.transaccionExitosa, Encoding.Unicode);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(EngineData.UrlBase + EngineData.UrlPersons);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Metodo donde consumo la web api:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadPersonToApi(string strToken,string jsonData)
    {
        string respuesta = string.Empty;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(EngineData.UrlBase + "PersonApi/CreatePerson", new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (respuesta == "transaccion exitosa")
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu API debes permitir un tamaño mayor de recepción de datos, en el archivo web.config agregas esto:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```